# Fourier Transform of Heaviside-like functions (with different $t=0$ values)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, step-function

Consider two functions $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ as follows:

$$
x_1(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & t<0 \\
1 & t \geq 0
\end{array}\right.
$$

$$
x_2(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & t\leq 0 \\
1 & t > 0
\end{array}\right.
$$

Do they have same Fourier transforms?

As I know, the first one's Fourier transform is $F_1(\omega) =
\pi \delta(\omega)+\frac{1}{j \omega}$. I know we can get this by calculating Fourier transform of $
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
e^{-\alpha t} & t \geq 0 \\
0 & t<0
\end{array}\right.
$ and finding its limit as $\alpha \to 0$.

I thought the Fourier transform of the second one should be the same. But I attended a Signals & Systems course and the lecturer said that there are some subtle difference between the two (But he didn't elaborated on the difference).

So my question is do their Fourier transform really differ? And if they don't have any difference, does this mean Fourier transform is not injective?

Comment: When Heaviside is going to be inside an integral (in which the measure of $\{0\}$ is $0$) it doesn't matter. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Zero_argument) for definitions at $0$ according to other properties that you might want to have or not.

Comment: @plop
Does that mean Fourier Transform is not injective? i.e. two different functions have same transform?
More generally, does my question have any importance? The course lecturer spoke about this like it is a really important thing that was beyond the scope of the course. He said it is important in studying duality and also injective/bijective properties of Fourier Transform. Unfortunately I don't have access to the lecturer to ask about this.

Comment: No just Fourier transform, but integrals in general have that property. What people do in that context is to consider two functions equivalent when they differ in a set that is small enough that the integral doesn't change, a set of measure zero.